# Is it possible to only show an active list of Bluetooth Devices that are paired, on, and in range as opposed to showing all previous paired devices?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

I am currently working on an android app that connects to an arduino microprocessor with Bluetooth SPP capabilities. My app shows all previously paired bluetooth devices, but I wanted to know is it possible to only show paired devices that are currently turned ON? I have searched for an answer everywhere and have yet to find one, hopefully this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a `BluetoothAdapter,` and register a `BroadcastReceiver` to `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.` Store those found devices in some sort of list.

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

...
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices = new ArrayList<>();
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_FOUND)){
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            devices.add(bluetoothDevice);
        }
    }
};
```

You can also register the receiver to `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED` and `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` and handle them accordingly.

Note: Don't forget to register the broadcast receiver in the manifest and include necessary permissions.

Comment: so what I have currently is a bluetooth.getBondedDevices(); object which I then add to an Array Adapter within a for loop. Is it possible to implement BroadcastReciever within that loop so that it can sort out the devices that are on? From your code it looks like it adds any devices trying to be discovered but not ones that are already paired. Correct me if I'm wrong. And this code is in a DeviceList.java separate from the main activity.

Comment: You could simply initialize the array using `getBondedDevices()` and then add more devices through the `BroadcastReceiver.` To ensure that duplicate devices are not added, first check if the `ArrayAdapter` already contains a `BluetoothDevice` with the same address.

Comment: When implementing onReceive() in BroadcastReceive() there is still an error, that says BroadcastReciever() must implement onReceive(). Any thoughts? And does this work best in onCreate() when the list is being initialized?

Comment: See the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#FindingDevices

Comment: Thanks, yes so list is being displayed properly of all connected devices, but only revealing those that are transmitting/is on still does not happen.